# How to present VC on VC which is presented on Tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

When trying to present VC1 with `vc1.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen`
on VC2 which is presented on TabBar with `vc2.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen` is not presenting VC2 and in console getting message :

```
Attempt to present <Demo.Secreen2VC: 0x7fb103088260> on
 <UINavigationController: 0x7fb10282da00> (from <UINavigationController: 
0x7fb1020a9000>) which is already presenting <Demo.Secreen1VC: 0x7fb10142aee0>.
```

I think that we cannot present VC on another presented VC with presentation style: `vc1.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen`

Any Help would be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: add present code line ????

Comment: @Sh_Khan No, its just presentationstyle and simple presenting vc as `self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with the second present